# Convert date in YYYY/MM/DD format in MomentJS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using MomentJS for converting the date format.

I have a date in this format 2010/12/01 and I want to convert it to 01/12/2010 using MomentJS only.

I have another date in this format "12/02/2014" and I want to convert in "2014/12/02"

```
<!--begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false-->

<!--language: lang-js-->

    var date = moment(new Date(2010/12/01)).format("MMM Do h/mm");
    console.log(date);

<!--language: lang-html-->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<!--end snippet-->
```

How do I convert them using MomentJS

Comment: What's the output of the code you tried? And try this format: MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: I have date "12/02/2014" in this format I want to convert in "2014/12/02"

Comment: Use `new Date("2010/12/01")` instead of `new Date(2010/12/01)`. But RobGs answer is better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this:

```
moment('2010/12/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD').format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a Date library at all:

```
'2010/12/01'.split('/').reverse().join('/')
```

Comment: I have date "12/02/2014" in this format I want to convert in "2014/12/02"

Comment: @CrazyAboutJavascript thats exactly what is does. You really don't need Dates or moment.js to do this.

Comment: It just reverses the parts. If it's in d/m/y  format it will be converted to y/m/d format and *vice versa*.

Comment: Cool, down votes for a simple answer. Why reformat a string by parsing, converting to a Date, then formatting it as a string again? I guess if you **must** use a particular library, fine. But why?

Comment: Thanks for this! Clever fix and solved my problem :)

Answer (score 2):

sudoCode

```
moment('date-to-be-converted','format-of-date-to-be-converted').format('desired-format');

moment('12/02/2014','MM/DD/YYYY').format('YYYY/MM/DD');
```